# Correct z-score implementation for a hypothesis test in Python?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, python, z-score

I have been getting some bizarre z-score calculations and wanted to confirm whether my concept and/or implementation is correct.

I have a `pandas` DataFrame `df`:

```py
count1  count2  countd
127     1       -126
127     1       -126
127     3       -124
127     6       -121
127     12      -115
...
85      1       -84
4       100     96
127     11      -116
157     16      -141
201     7       -194
```

not sorted in any particular order, where `countd = count2 - count1`.

I observe the value $x$, where $x$ equals the sum of all `countd` values in `df`. Here, my null hypothesis is $H_0: x = 0$.

What I would like to analyze is the z-score and the p-value of $x$. Hence, I tried to implement $z = \frac{x-0}{\sigma}$ by

```py
x = df["countd"].sum()
mean = x/len(df)

num = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
  num += (df['countd'][i] - mean)**2

sd = math.sqrt(num/(len(df)-1))

z = x/sd

print(z)
```

The returning z-score, however, is 160.87, which is abnormally high. Is my implementation (and the understanding of the concept of z-score) correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want two separate dataframes in this case for a more efficient computation.

Say your dataframe is split into two lists, `list1` and `list2`. Then:

```
sd = math.sqrt((np.std(list1) ** 2 + np.std(list2) ** 2)/len(df))

print((np.mean(list1)-np.mean(list2))/sd)
```

You could of course simplify it using notations, but these are the basic gist.

Answer (score 0):

Calling variables as $c_1,c_2,c_d=c_1-c_2$. It's not correct because $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $c_d$, not $x$. In order to test for $x$, you need many $x$'s, i.e. many different dataframes so that your sample size becomes more than $1$.

I think, testing for $x=0$ is equivalent to testing for $c_d=0$; so, what you should do is to revise your hypothesis. Then, the $z$ value (if $n$ is small, use t-test) becomes $$z=\frac{\bar{c_d}-0}{s_d}$$
where $s_d$ is the sample deviation (as yours).